# Too much time taking to read a USB flash drive when connected to system

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb-flash-drive

I use HP G62 laptop which runs on Windows 7. For 3 days it takes more time to read a pen drive when connected, that is the pen drive appears not suddenly in the My Computer after it is connected. Before that it used to appear suddenly in My Computer when it was plugged.

Why is this lag now ? How can I avoid this lag ?

Comment: How long does it take to show up now? Has anything changed since it started taking a long time? By that I mean, have you loaded the pen drive with a ton of data, or have you installed new USB drivers

Comment: @DevonParsons Approximately 1 minute. I have installed a new USB drive.